# Subspace of $R^3$

Tags: vector-spaces

If  $$ W = \{(a, b, c) : a+b+c=0; a, b,c \in R\}$$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ then what would be the dimensions of $W$?.

I believe that this signifies a complete space  $R^3$ also containing the origin but my teacher says that it must be 2-D subspace of   $R^3$.  I don't get it why its dimension is 2. Can anybody help me apprehend intuitively?

Comment: Observe that for any element $\;(a,b,c)\in W\;$ we can choose *freely* two of the three variables. This means the dimension is two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that

$$u=(a,b,c)\in W\iff u=(a,b,-a-b)=a(1,0,-1)+b(0,1,-1)\in S$$
where

$$S=\operatorname{Span}((1,0,-1),(0,1,-1))$$
so $W=S$ which is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ of dimension $2$.

Notice also that using the linear form $\varphi:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R,(a,b,c)\mapsto a+b+c$, we see that $W$ is nothing but the kernel of $\varphi$ and its dimension is 2 due to the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Can  I also  say  that dimension of (a, b, 0)  is also 2?

Comment: Yes the dimension of the subspace $\{(a,b,0)\mid a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ is 2.

Answer (score 3):

Think in terms of 'degrees of freedom', or number of parameters.

If you take any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, then there is exactly one choice for $c$ so that $a+b+c=0$.  So, you need at most two values to describe any $(a,b,c)\in W$, and therefore its dimension is at most 2.

To be more formal, you need to find a basis consisting of two linearly independent vectors.  You can see how to do this by noting that $c=-a-b$; so, a basis for this space is $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$.  Why?  Because
$$
(a,b,c)=(a,b,-a-b)=a(1,0-1)+b(0,1,-1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of it is that the condition $a+b+c=0$ is a "one-dimensional constraint", i.e. the number of constrainst corresponds to the reduction in the number of dimensions compared to the dimension of the ambient space.

Thus the dimension of the space should be $$3 \text{ degrees of freedom}- 1 \text{ constraint} = 2 \text{ dimensions}.$$

More geometrically, it is the plane consisting of all vectors which are orthogonal to the vector $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. a [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and thus of dimension $3-1=2$. Although you may not know about [orthogonal complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) yet, so this might not help much.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map
$$
f\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R},
\quad
f\colon (a,b,c)\mapsto a+b+c
$$
Prove it is linear and that its kernel is $W$; since it is also surjective, the rank-nullity theorem will tell you that $\dim W=3-1=2$.